# displaying php on a page

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have some php code that will display favourites of 3 different options that the user has clicked.
I need to display this in a single page of my html app site, i was wondering how to do this?
Presumably plugging it in at the top wouldn't work, and i can't just insert it into the div?
Do i need some jquery? how and what do i need to do ?

```
<div data-role="page" id="page3" class="ui-content" >
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-header">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn" data-rel="back">Go Back</a>
        <h1><img src="logo.png" alt="logo" /></h1>
        <h1>Page Three</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   
        this is where i want the script
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>All Rights Reserved ICook 2015</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could change the file to `*.php` and include the file, which just has to return the favorites, into this file !

Comment: @Rizier123 "change the file to `*.php`"? What is that meant to say?

Comment: @arkascha That the file gets parsed as php

Comment: @Rizier123 This means that you change your filename from yourfilename.html to yourfilename.php

Comment: Ah, now _that_ is something people can understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix PHP and HTML on the same page as long as the extension is .php and the PHP is held inside of appropriate tags.

For example:

```
<p>The current amount of users is <?php echo 50; ?></p>
```

> Or if you want to include an existing PHP file, do the following:

```
<?php
include "some_file.php";
?>
```

Comment: server can be configured to compile php in other extensions such as `.html` also

Comment: do both of these options have to be a .php file? i want mine to be html but when im doing the include, its not working at all

Comment: As charlieftl noted, you can configure your server to compile PHP inside of HTML files. Though, in your case, you'll need to change the extension to .php